# make android app downloadable

Tags: android, download, installation

There all,
Is there a way to make an android app be installable directly through a link of a web page.

E.g. , I have a webpage called www.mypage.com with some links each of pointing to an app whose name is "Myapp.apk". I would like that the user, just clicking on this link, can download and directly install it.

I have already seen around the web and I have been sugested to use some FileManager, but it is not the best solution for me.
Thanks

Comment: APK is just a file, it's no different from downloading a jpg or a zip file. Just put it on a server.

Comment: What Tom says is right. But also keep in mind this won't be an official "install" it will basically be the same as loading the apk through an emulator. It's an unsigned version of your app, but feature-wise is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to do this.  That's for security-  otherwise you'd have every website stealth installing apps on people.  You can download the apk and then use a file manager to install it, but you can't download and install in one action through a browser.

Answer (score -1):

No you can't do it.If it was possible then whats the use of GOOGLE PLAY.
what you can do is forward it to your app page on Google play.